# How do I link internal files in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, filepath, routerlink

I'm trying to link my login page from the navbar. This is what I have for navbar:

```
<div class="navbar-container">
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav center-align">
    <li>
      <div class="user-view center-align">
        <a><i class="medium material-icons close-button">close</i></a>
      </div>
    <li><a routerLink="../login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="small material-icons {{updateMe()}}">filter_list</i></a>
</div>
```

And this is my file structure:

[image: file structure]

However, it just doesn't link to the component. The error I get is:

> core.js:1542 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'

Am I using relative paths wrong? How can I fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, you need to set all paths in routes array which is present in **app.module.ts**.
Please check if you've developed it perfectly.

Comment: ahh I hadn't added it to my app routing module - thank you! I'll accept your answer when 5mins is up :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the route configured in your app.routing.module.ts as follows,

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent,useAsDefault: true}
])
```

Comment: why did you remove the answer?